# Koken CMS If class is add class to another element (multiple cases)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, addclass, koken

Besides a different color for each nav item when they are active i need to have my site-title (logo background color) another color for each page/album.

When a link inside the nav is active, `.k-nav-current` is automatically appended.

So i've tried this:

```
if ($("#main li:nth-child(2)").hasClass('.k-nav-current')) {
    $("#site-title").addClass("babycurrent");
} else {

};


.babycurrent{
background: rgb(35,235,0);
}
```

Or instead of `#main li:nth-child()` i've tried:
`#main a#unique_nav_itemid`
`a#unique_nav_itemid`

But none of these solutions are working.

Comment: One problem is that even if you are on the homepage, the logo has the class `k-nav-current`.  It will always be true.

Comment: i think we misunderstood each other.  The `K-nav-current` is assigned to the link in the navigation. 

when this class is assigned i want to add another class to the `#site-title id` So i can style the background of the logo for each page

Comment: But that's the thing.  As far as I can tell, it's always assigned no matter what page you are on (even when you just navigate to http://itook.nl/admin).  So then your function to add a class to the `#site-title` will always be called immediately after page load.

Comment: yes you're correct it's always assigned no matter which page you are. And the function has to be called after every page load.So the function goes in an if else statement and is checking to which nav element the k-nav-current is assigned and then it adds for every if statement another class to `#site-title` 

my javascript is now just loaded in as:  main.js and in that file just the if else statement and nothing more.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do.  See my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method you can use to test to see if the element exists in the document:

```
if($('.k-nav-current').length) {
    $("#site-title").addClass("babycurrent");
}
```

of course if length is `0`, it is considered "falsey".  any other positive number is "truthy".

However, for any further help, we will need to see the actual markup.

#### EDIT:

For your current setup, you are trying to use `#main li:nth-child(2)` and checking its class.  The class is actually applied to the anchor.  You need to use `#main li:nth-child(2) a`

```
if ($("#main li:nth-child(2) a").hasClass('k-nav-current')) {
    $("#site-title").addClass("babycurrent");
}
```

Though it might be better to just use something like this (considering ids are unique):

```
if ($("#baby").hasClass('k-nav-current')) {
    $("#site-title").addClass("babycurrent");
}
```

Lastly, if you really want it dynamic, you can do something like this:

```
var current = $("a.k-nav-current")[0].id.replace('#','');
$("#site-title").addClass(current + "current");
```

#### EDIT:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if ($("#baby").hasClass('k-nav-current')) {
    $("#site-title").addClass("babycurrent");
  }
});

// or you can do this (commented out) /*

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var current = $("a.k-nav-current")[0].id.replace('#','');
  $("#site-title").addClass(current + "current");
});

*/
```

Comment: i just copy paste the dynamic one in my main.js. Now there is just those two lines. i get the error: 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.`

Comment: Ah! that's right.  Not all of them are contained in that `#main`.  there's still the logo.  I'l edit my answer.

Comment: i get still the same error

so tried the if statement and there i get no error but there is none class added in (developer tools)

Comment: @Rik sorry again.  It needs to not have the `.` for the hasClass function.

Comment: also you should probably wrap that in a document ready function

Comment: i don't know what i'm doing wrong but i see still no added class in the `site-title`

Comment: you're my hero!! really really thanks for helping me!

editted your post as answer